# Pair swap elements in list using Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am a Ocaml beginner, and am not able to understand tail recursiveness or list iteration. How can we iterate through list is 2s and swap the pairs?

```
let rec swap = function
| a :: (b :: _ as t) -> b::a::swap t | smaller -> smaller;;
let newlist = swap [1;2;3;4];;
List.iter print_int newlist;
```

For example, 1234, the swap function is swapping 1 and 2, and then the list head is still at 2, and its swapping 2 and 3 whereas it should be at 3 and swapping 3 and 4.

Comment: You should show some code you've written and explain why it doesn't seem to be working. As a general hint, if you break a list of length n into two pieces of length 2 and n - 2, you have an easy problem to solve (of length 2) and a smaller instance of the same problem.

Comment: let rec swap = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> b ::a:: swap t;;

Comment: @dj007 you should edit your question with the content of your comment and explain a little bit what is not working with the code you're showing. Hint: the warning about non-exhaustiveness you're probably getting from the compiler/interpreter is important. As already said by Jeffrey Scofield, what happens when the argument of swap is of form `[a]` (a list with a single element) or `[]` (the empty list)?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in `swap` should be

```
let rec swap = function
    | a :: b :: tail -> b :: a :: (swap tail)
    | whatever -> whatever
```

This way you swap two elements on the head and proceed with what after those.

However, there is a problem here. Let's see what happens, say, in the case of `swap [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` call:

1. `swap` is called with `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]`
2. `a` matched with 1, `b` matched with 2, and...

....2.1. `swap` is called with `[3; 4; 5; 6]`

....2.2. inside this second call `a` is matched with 3, `b` is matched with 4, and...

........2.2.1. `swap` is called with `[5; 6]`

........2.2.2. inside this third call `a` is matched with 5, `b` is matched with 6, and ...

............2.2.2.1. `swap` is called with `[]` (empty list)

............2.2.2.2. This call returns back empty list

........2.2.3. ...and it is picked up in the previous `swap` call to add `b` and `a` to the start of it, producing `6 :: 5 :: []` or `[6; 5]`

........2.2.4. which is returned

....2.3. ...and it is picked up in the previous `swap` call to add (its own) `b` and `a` to the start of it, producing `4 :: 3 :: [6; 5]` or `[4; 3; 6; 5]`

....2.4. which is returned

3. ...and it is picked up in the previous `swap` call to add (its own) `b` and `a` to the start of it, producing `2 :: 1 :: [4; 3; 6; 5]` or `[2; 1; 4; 3; 6; 5]`
4. which is returned as a final result

Notice how the whole chain of `swap` calls had to be travelled in both directions:

call 1, `swap [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` => call 2, `swap [3; 4; 5; 6]` => call 3, `swap [5; 6]` => call 4, `swap []`, returns `[]`, now going back => call 3, returns `[6; 5]` => call 2, returns `[4; 3; 6; 5]` => call 1, returns `[2; 1; 4; 3; 6; 5]`.

This means that the whole time the program is going "down", it should keep the previous path in the memory, so it could return back. If your list is, say, two million entries, the whole path will be one million calls, and it should be kept in memory. You'll run out of stack space if you run such thing.

How to solve this problem? The usual technique is to use some kind of "accumulator".

```
let rec swap_helper acc = function
    | a :: b :: tail -> swap_helper (a :: b :: acc) tail
    | a :: [] -> a :: acc
    | [] -> acc ;;

let swap2 lst = List.rev (swap_helper [] lst)
```

What are those functions? Let's try to see what happens if we call `swap2 [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]`. It starts with calling `swap_helper [] [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]`.

1. `a` is matched with 1, `b` is matched with 2, `tail` is matched with `[3; 4; 5; 6]`, so we call `swap_helper [1; 2] [3; 4; 5; 6]`. But lo and behold! When this next call returns, we are not doing with the result anything at all, so there is no reason to go back -- compiler will produce the code to  return the result we'll get in `swap_helper [1; 2] [3; 4; 5; 6]` immediately, without going back to original code -- because there's nothing left to do with that result in the original call. *This is called tail call optimization.*
2. Now we are in `swap_helper [1; 2] [3; 4; 5; 6]` call, where `a` is matched with 3, `b` is matched with 4 and `tail` is matched with `[5; 6]`, so we call next `swap_helper [3; 4; 1; 2] [5; 6]` and there's again nothing left to do after that, so we are not going to return here anymore!
3. So, `swap_helper [3; 4; 1; 2] [5; 6]` call. Here `a` is 5, `b` is 6, `tail` is `[]`. We proceed to `swap_helper [5; 6; 3; 4; 1; 2] []` and we are *not* going back here anymore, since there's nothing left to do!
4. `swap_helper [5; 6; 3; 4; 1; 2] []` hits the last case of match and returns immediately `[5; 6; 3; 4; 1; 2]` -- but not to any intermediate `swap_helper` calls, they are already forgotten, there's no work to do in those left -- but straight to the original `swap2` call!

Now in `swap2` we reverse the list we got from `swap_helper` and get our `[2; 1; 4; 3; 6; 5]`, as desired.

So, to repeat: in this code when `swap_helper` calls itself, there is nothing left to do, so there's no reason to return, so there's no reason to spend memory to remember "way back", as we are not going to go back. In the original code we could not do that, because `swap` was calling itself and still  had to glue `a` and `b` to the result of that second call after it's ready.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for the answer ! Sorry if it sounded silly, this is my first time with functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer doesn't explicitly point out the key misunderstanding causing this problem. The issue lies in the associativity of `as`.  In the pattern `a :: (b :: _ as t)` the as binds `t` to the entire `b :: _` pattern. `as` will bind the entire pattern to its left. Parentheses can be used to disambiguate.

Therefore, when `swap t` is called, `t` is the entire tail, and not the tail of the tail as was clearly intended. If we make that one change, the function works correctly.

```
# let rec swap = function
    | a :: (b :: t) -> b::a::swap t 
    | smaller -> smaller;;
val swap : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# swap [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [2; 1; 4; 3]
```

We might clean this up a bit for readability.

```
let rec swap = function
  | a::b::t -> b :: a :: swap t
  | lst -> lst
```